# Merge [transparent] and [transparency]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I propose merging [transparent](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/transparent) (*34 questions*) with [transparency](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/transparency) (*79 questions*). I think it's pretty ***clear*** to see why they should be merged.

...

... yeah, that pun was pretty terrible, [even by retag request standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests).

......

......

......

...... not sure what else to put here, so here's a Pandicorn.

---

[image: Pandicorn]

Comment: Downvote for a useless panda, upvote for the bad pun... ;)

Comment: @Burgi Where do you see a panda? All I see is a [pandicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns/351462).

Comment: Fair point well made.

Comment: I don’t see the point.  Oh, wait, that ***is*** the point.     :-)     ⁠

Comment: I'm tempted to just get on and make this change, but I can't see which should be merged into which. There's no clear "master" tag out of the two.

Comment: @Mokubai My vote is [transparency]. It has more questions tagged to it, and sounds a bit more general.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro that was about the only justification for direction I could see as well. [Transparency] feels more about the process and result than just having something that is "transparent".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merge done.

```
updating post history, 49 rows affected (pipe delimited) 
updating posts, 34 rows affected (pipe delimited) 
updating PostTags associations, 32 rows affected 
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected 
updating DocTags, 0 rows affected 
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected 
updating count for master tag, new count: 111 
tag remapping of [transparency] and [transparent] complete! 
remapping 0 synonyms 
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped! 
0 tracked tag badges were remapped! 
Tag Synonym transparent -> transparency was approved!
```